# Sorting order by 'Pick Status' using the Exact Online API

Tags: exact-online

I am developing an application using the Exact Online API, for one of the features I'd like to display an overview of the orders that are ready to be picked per SalesChannel.

After searching through the [official API reference](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResources.aspx) multiple times I can't seem to find a suitable method or filter that would allow me to request or at least aggregate this data. I was wondering if someone knows a method or filter that would allow me to obtain said data.

After inspecting the API requests the Exact Online UI makes it seems that there at least is internal support for the Pick Status. The internal API uses two flags specifically: 'PickOrderHeaderStatus' and 'PickOrderEntryId'.